# Read JSON response in JQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my json response

```
{"COLUMNS":["LABEL1", "LABEL2", "RATE1", "RATE2"], "DATA":[["tps", "tvq", 10.0, 20.0]]}
```

And I want to be able to loop only over the DATA element.

I don't have any code because I have no clue how to do this. Just learning this new language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// response.DATA is an array with just one element
var dataElements = response.DATA;

// The first element in that array is another array containing your data
var firstData = dataElements[0];

// Loop through and access each individual element
for (var i = 0; i < firstData.length; i++) {
  alert(firstData[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for not only the code but for the explanation...greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only arrays inside the `DATA` and you need each array, then do it like this:

```
for(var i in response.DATA){
    alert(response.DATA[i]);
}
```

Otherwise if you want all the values `tps, tvq, 10.0, and 20.0`, then do it like this:

```
for(var i in response.DATA[0]){
    alert(response.DATA[0][i]);
}
```

---

#### Update

```
var arrData = response.DATA[0],
    sizeOfData = arrData.length,
    i = 0;

for(i; i < sizeOfData; i++){
    alert(arrData[i]);
}
```

Comment: That won't work usefully (since `DATA[0]` is the only element in `DATA` and is an array itself) and it's not good to loop through arrays with `for..in` loops.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I had edited already. Any benchmarks on the speed between `for .. in` and `for`, please enlighten me.

Comment: Speed isn't the isssue. Things like `Array.prototype.forEach = function(){}` are the problem. `for..in` should be used for looping over object properties; `for` for array elements.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Great, enlightened!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i in response.DATA){
    alert(response.DATA[i];
}
```